# Getting the variables from strings with R formula symbols

Tags: r, regex, syntax

I have a very simple question. I want to be able to split `"Income*Educ"` or  `"I(Income^2)"))` into strings with their respective variables, so: `"Income" "Educ"` and `"Income"` respectively. However, I do not know which type it will be..

The following fixes: `"Income*Educ"`

```
strsplit(gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", str), " +")[[1]]
```

And this one almost fixes : `"I(Income^2)"))`

```
strsplit(gsub("[^A-Za-z]+", "", str), " +")[[1]]
```

How can I make this function for both forms?

Comment: You can use `terms()` to accomplish this

Comment: If you can explain the rules that can be coded with regex, then it is possible. Else, use the solutions suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to avoid regular expression if you want to to parse R code. There are plenty of built in tools for that. If you have a formula like

```
ff <- . ~ Income*Educ + I(Income^2)
```

you can get all the variables with

```
all.vars(ff)
```

This keeps the "." as the response but you can filter that out.